# Permanently setup nomodeset kernel parameters

Tags: xubuntu

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 5577 with Nvidia 1050 graphics card.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS latest version but it is getting stuck every time I boot it. I have to manual set kernel. I solved my issue, but when I shutdown and start again I have to do the same setup for `nomodeset`.

How can I permanently set `nomodeset` kernel parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)